# Is Memcache's append() internally atomic?

Tags: concurrency, memcached

Basically, if two processes attempt to append to the same key at the same time, is there any chance that one will ever overwrite the other?

e.g.:

Process 1 appends "a" to the key "k"

Process 2 appends "b" to the key "k"

Are we guaranteed to have two characters (either "ab" or "ba") as the value after we perform these actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, memcached does not do a read/write to append so concurrency is ensured